# Visual SourceSafe Horror Stories...?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I have heard some pretty bad review about source safe (VSS) but no real examples. Anyone have a good example/story?

Comment: sure - not the place for that, though. Basically had to move to a new repository for a medium size project every 4-6 months (and loosing all the history up to then) due to fragmentation and data corruption - for a whole three years!

Comment: If you are being nagged to move to git or svn or TFS and think that VSS is good enough, go try to export your repository.  If you can't export it, then it is safe to say the source control tree is corrupt, despite what Analyze is saying.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039583/detecting-vss-corruption-through-export-to-svn

The real horror story in my opinion with VSS is that users lock files, which is drag on productivity while dev wait for other dev to unlock those files.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520926/any-real-life-visual-source-safe-horror-stories

Answer (score 2):

**VSS: No warning for conflict when you do checkin.** My colleague used to eliminate my changes. And then I had to drill down into comparing version histories for the check-in he did. He just used to ignore each time :(